# How to fix an error concerning an index-variable in PL/SQL: PLS-00103

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have some PL/SQL code and essentially try to run a loop with an index variable:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_print_nr(v_nr IN NUMBER) IS
  v_index IN OUT NUMBER := 1;
BEGIN
    FOR v_index IN 1 .. v_nr LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Value is: '||v_index);
      v_index :=  v_index +1;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

ORACLE SQL Developer pounds me with the following error message:

> Error(3,9): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IN" when expecting one of the following:
>   constant exception      table long double ref    char time timestamp interval date binary national character    nchar

IMPORTANT NOTE:
When I skip the IN OUT before the NUMBER Declaration, I get another (even more severe error):

> Error(7,3): PLS-00363: expression 'v_index' cannot be used as an assignment target

Assigning something to v_index is the functional core of the procedure. So simply omitting IN OUT even worsens the problem.

Comment: Variable declarations don't have `IN OUT`. [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/scalar-variable-declaration.html) has examples if you are stuck. You might also check the [syntax for `for` loops](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/FOR-LOOP-statement.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FOR ... LOOP construct handles the declaration and increment of the index.

So all you need is ...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_print_nr(v_nr IN NUMBER) IS
BEGIN
    FOR v_index IN 1 .. v_nr LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Value is: '||v_index);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

This construct is as self-contained as the equivalent would be in Java:

```
for (int v_index = 0; v_index < v_nr; v_index++) {
   System.out.println(v_index);
}
```

Comment: Since the loop seems to administrate each of its index-related variables, it prevented me from assigning any other values.

Comment: Why would you want to assign any other values?